# Facing issue in Postgres loading extension

Tags: gis, postgis, pgrouting, osgeo

I am trying to to load `pgrouting` in extension in `postgis` database named as "routing" the problem I am facing is I type in osgeo shell in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\bin"  "psql -U postgres routing"` and it gives the error of  `"psql : illegal option --u"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that your wrote "-U" and not "-u" in lower case? Because this is what the error tells you. If you connect to the database routing using: `psql -U postgres routing` then it should be all right.